# Transform the number returned from input type month into text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added an `input type=month` in my page and I am getting the value using jquery as per example `2017-08`.
How can I transform it to `August, 2017` ?

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: Please share some code so that we can help

Comment: i suggest you should use a datedropper plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a array of month name and use like this

```js
allMonths = ["January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October","November", "December"];

var date = new Date("2017-08");
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(allMonths[month]+", "+year);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How the value of `1` is taking the array value `january` which have the index of 0 ans not 1

Comment: @LaraCh :  It becomes `0` when you use `date.getMonth()` : https://jsfiddle.net/ap1zjfo6/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve this:

```
moment('2017-08', 'YYYY-MM').format('MMMM, YYYY');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

`moment('2017-08', 'YYYY-MM').format('MMM, YYYY');`